# Predefining joins in Simple.Data

Tags: join, simple.data

I have a table *Users* with a foreign key to another table *Department*.
The User object has a POCO for the department. I can select a user with the department-poco being populated with the following Simple.Data by-id query:

```
db.Users.With(db.Users.Departments.As("Department")).FindByUserID(userId);
```

Now I not only load users by id but also by name which results in the following query:

```
db.Users.With(db.Users.Departments.As("Department")).FindByUserName(userName);
```

To make it DRY I thought I  might refactor the join into a variable and reuse it:

```
var userJoinedWithDepartment = db.Users.With(db.Users.Departments.As("Department"));
userJoinedWithDepartment.FindByUserID(userId);
```

However that causes trouble. At some other point I get an error about a already open transaction which leads me to believe that by defining that variable that already executes something in the background. I can't see a SQL statement being executed.

Is there a way to get around that and reuse the definitions for joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to make it a `var` but a `dynamic`.

```
dynamic userJoinedWithDepartment = db.Users.With(db.Users.Departments.As("Department"));
userJoinedWithDepartment.FindByUserID(userId);
```